# Kotlin coroutine + LiveData + DataBinding problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have a issue using Kotlin coroutine + LiveData + DataBinding problem.

My code is below

```
class TempViewModel: ViewModel() {

 val creatorInfo: LiveData<CreatorInfo> = liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
        val data = CreatorInfoSettingRepository.requestCreatorInfo().body()
        emit(data!!)
    }
}
```

and xml use databinding like this

```
 <TextView
      android:text="@{viewModel.creatorInfo.email}" />
 <TextView
      android:text="@{viewModel.creatorInfo.phone}" />

 ....
```

I checked that fetching data(CreatorInfo) from server(retrofit2) is successful, 
but data is not applied to UI by databinding.

also when check observing like below, observe block is invoked.

```
viewModel.creatorInfo.observe(fragment, Observer { creatorInfo ->
            Log.d("ssong","test")
        })
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: I image did you already try make the data binding from the activity observer right?

Comment: Add some more code of your Activity please.

Comment: Is CreatorInfi changed?

Comment: @Dak28 no I am using fragment. Also this code was implemented by RxJava not coroutine and worked well before. So lifecycle and fragment linking with databinding is right.

Answer (score 5):

Did you add this in you main activity?

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected the `Binding` with your actual `ViewModel`?

```
someFragmentActivityBinding.viewModel = myViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

There was my mistake.
It works well.
There was code that hide TextViews..(View.gone) (So I thought databinding does not work well).

Problem is solved. Thank you guys.